# Phonegap + DB storage

Tags: ios, cordova

In my app i need to import Facebook contacts. What is the best practice ro store contacts information?

I have two options:

1. Local storage
2. External database (mysql for example)

Thank you!

Comment: I would recommend storing it on local database (HTML5 websql) would be best option as in one of my app i have stored entire Quran in local database with 6700 rows

Comment: As far as i understand if you need to insert all records at first time using web sql will slow down the system, I would prefer you to go through http://html5sql.com/ I have used same. This is much faster for bulk data insertion. Hope this helps :)

Comment: down vote
accept
But what if I want eventually flush local device DB to the webserver's MySQL? Is not it better to import data into MySQL and allow my app to interact with remote mysql ?

Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: Nope this is not advisable as assume that i have 1500+ friends in my facebook so every time app opens up it might take 4-5 seconds to download the data, so you will be wasting time and internet of the user.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest [this SQLite wrapper](https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin)

It's use is very simple. Similar use like web sql

```
// Wait for Cordova to load
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// Cordova is ready
function onDeviceReady() {
  var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "my.db"});
  // ...
}
```

Example:

```
// Wait for Cordova to load
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// Cordova is ready
function onDeviceReady() {
  var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "my.db"});

  db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_table');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table (id integer primary key, data text, data_num integer)');

    // demonstrate PRAGMA:
    db.executeSql("pragma table_info (test_table);", [], function(res) {
      console.log("PRAGMA res: " + JSON.stringify(res));
    });

    tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO test_table (data, data_num) VALUES (?,?)", ["test", 100], function(tx, res) {
      console.log("insertId: " + res.insertId + " -- probably 1");
      console.log("rowsAffected: " + res.rowsAffected + " -- should be 1");

      db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql("select count(id) as cnt from test_table;", [], function(tx, res) {
          console.log("res.rows.length: " + res.rows.length + " -- should be 1");
          console.log("res.rows.item(0).cnt: " + res.rows.item(0).cnt + " -- should be 1");
        });
      });

    }, function(e) {
      console.log("ERROR: " + e.message);
    });
  });
}
```

See more at plugin documentation.

Comment: If you need bulk import at first run this might slow down. Alternatively we can use http://html5sql.com/

Comment: might slow down! you're not sure then! I'm using it for quite some time and it's performance looks okay to me. And user2257338 didn't mention about anything 'bulk import at first run' @AadilKeshwani

Comment: It will slow down as i have used to insert bunch of 6700 queries. For single query it will not effect try to insert more than 500 queries at single time and it will hang up.